# Error I'm getting in my python code? Error is this line: cipher = AES.new (key)

Tags: python-3.x

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES


key = b' \xbf\xc0\x85'
message = 'This secret message is encrypted'
cipher = AES.new (key)

def pad(s):
     return s + ((16-len(s) % 16) * '{')

def encrypt(plaintext):
     global cipher
     return cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext))

def decrypt(ciphertext):
     global cipher
     dec = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')
     l = dec.count('{')
     return dec[:len(dec)-l]

print("Message:",message)
encrypted = encrypt(message)
decrypted = decrypt(encrypted)
print("Encrypted:", encrypted)
print("Decrypted:", decrypted)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\tommy_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\test13.py", line 6, in 
>       cipher = AES.new (key)
>   TypeError: new() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mode'

Answer (score 0):

First you have to put the object into a variable:

```
obj = AES()
cipher = obj.key(key)
```